# Projecting a light onto a quad

Tags: c#, unity, mathematics, vector

I need to project the light onto the quad and use its value for translating the vertices.

I'm currently having 6 vertices,  two quads,
The points are
A  X  C
B  Y  D

Point X, Y are coming from two ray casting downwards.

```
C =  X + RightVector
D =  Y +  RightVector
A =  X - RightVector
B =  Y - RightVector
```

Now I want to translate the vertices based on lightDirectionVector, how would I do that ? I have a directional light, and that mesh of the two quads acting as a shadow quad.

```
    Vector3 lightDir = mDirectionalLight.transform.forward;
    Vector3 normLight = lightDir.normalized;
    normaLight.y = 0;
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking here.  Can you add a diagram or screenshot or something that explains what you're trying to do?

Comment: @NathanReed I have uploaded a picture.

Comment: On your screenshot the shadow is wrongly rotated, you don´t expect that to change, right? So if I understand you correctly, you want to project the light direction onto the plane given by those vertices?

Comment: @Slin yes typically that's what I want to do. project the light direction onto the plane. just simulate a fake shadow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if projection is actually the correct word for this, but I hope it is what you are looking for.

First you need the planes normal which is the cross product of the directions from one of your vertices to two of the others, which in case of your image could be C-A and B-A. (the three vertices may not lay in the same line, there is a simple mathematical term for it, but I guess I forgot it :( something with linearity...).

If you got the normal, you can calculate the closest distance of some arbitrary point of which your light direction is the position vector by building the dot product between your light direction and the normal.

Now you can calculate the position of that point within the plane by moving it along the normal towards the plane with the previously calculated distance: newdirection = direction - normal * dot(normal, direction)

But this will only give you the direction to the closest point on your plane to some arbitrary point defined by the light direction and I currently can´t get my head around if it really exactly is what you need or if it is only close.

Comment: looks correct to me, but I can't Imagine/visualize at all what you explained unfortunately :(. Especially this: , you can calculate the closest distance of some arbitrary point of which your light direction is the position vector by building the dot product between your light direction and the normal.I think the math term is co-planer. Would you recommend something to let me solve those kind of problems in future?

Comment: The term I was looking for was "independent" :) because your two vectors need to be independent.

Comment: they are in the same mesh.I can't visualize your solution and how did you come up with it. also please recommend me something to read so that I be able to solve those problems in future ?

Comment: is it wrong to just calculate one Normal from just one Plane (X-A, Y-A) for example?

Comment: Check this for a better explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605556/how-to-project-a-3d-point-to-a-3d-plane

Comment: If you always calculate your planes vertices the way you wrote in your question they will all lay in the same plane, so you only need one normal. If they don´t you need a normal for each plane.

Comment: a recommendation please :), also why can't I use the dot product of light's forward vector with my right forward vector and use that value for shifting the vertices?

Comment: I learned these things at school and then again at university so it is probably part of any introduction to linear algebra. Also a quite complete source for 3D math is http://www.euclideanspace.com/ and of course wikipedia although it sometimes states some things as given, but they actually depend a lot on your own implementations for other things. In the end it is mostly about getting an understanding of the math, knowing the correct keywords to search for and most helpful in my opinion: being able to imagine what is happening to the vectors if they would represent positions of real objects.

Comment: The dot product will only give you a scalar value, so you still need to figure out the direction you want to move it to. Also what is your "right" forward vector? As that would already need to be the direction you are looking for.

Comment: I mean by right vector, is the right vector of my object, which is in the picture is the bicycle. The forward vector is the light's forward vector. value = LightForward.MyRighVector, can't I use it ? but the problem it will be negative values when I rotate the bicycle, how would I deal with negative dot product angles?

Comment: negative values would only mean that you need to move in the opposite direction which should be fine. But the right vector would give you wrong results as you need the sun direction within the plane and that would only give you correct results if the sun comes exactly from the left or the right of the bike as otherwise you would want the shadow to shear and not just to scale.

Comment: so the dot product approach would fail, even If I use the forward vector of my bike instead of its right vector? isn't it?

Comment: yes, the shadow wouldn´t behave the way it should that way ;)